# Allow images from S3 only under my domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to allow static images stored in my aws s3 to be accessed only under my domain xyz.com?

I'm aware of that doesn't secure the images, I just wanna avoid people to view the images by pasting the s3 url in a new browser tab

thanks

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4

Comment: I wanna kiss you, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b) in the comments, an Amazon S3 bucket policy can be created.

Amongst the many possible policy settings is a `Referrer` option:

> Suppose you have a website with domain name (`www.example.com` or `example.com`) with links to photos and videos stored in your S3 bucket, `examplebucket`. By default, all the S3 resources are private, so only the AWS account that created the resources can access them. To allow read access to these objects from your website, you can add a bucket policy that allows `s3:GetObject` permission with a condition, using the `aws:referer` key, that the get request must originate from specific webpages. The following policy specifies the `StringLike` condition with the `aws:Referer` condition key.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See documentation: [Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)